# verify login credentials for external site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a website that asks a user for his login credentials for a different site. This site is external to my server. Something like craigslist.com. After the user provides me with his username and password I want to be able to verify that these credentials are valid for that site, otherwise I want to let the user know that he incorrectly entered the credentials for the external site. Is there a way for me to do this? I would prefer if the solution was in asp.net(vb.net/aspx) but, i'm willing to work with other languages. I'll find a way to make them communicate if I have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Absolutely. A quick caveat: you should be using a good security model to protect these secrets that the user provides you, which is a different and complex topic. You are taking on the responsibility of storing their credentials, which although the data is hopefully encrypted by your app in storage, your application has the ability to decrypt it into plaintext, which puts an onus of responsibility on your application. You may also want to make sure you aren't breaking any TOS with the remote website.*

But for this question, what you essentially want is code that opens a web request to simulate a user manually logging in on the other site. You will POST the login form on that remote server from your .NET code, on behalf of your user. A strategy for writing the code:

- Use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to examine the web traffic that is sent by your browser when you are posting that login form on the remote site manually in a web browser using known good credentials.
- Find out what fields need to be posted in a valid request, pay attention to any special requirements they may be checking for (best to make your programmatic request look exactly like a real browser request:
- Pass all the same headers like User Agent, Accept, Referer, Cookies (for extra credit...maybe they are looking for an established session cookie that you need to setup with an initial setup request before doing the POST), etc. Include all of the same fields in the POST that a browser would...watch out for hidden fields that a browser posts, and any request-specific fields (which would require you to make an intial HTTP GET request to have the server give you some valid ones, then a post-request to send the payload). Some forms have bot prevention by setting display:none on fields...so of course don't post those as a manual user login wouldn't (as you will see in Fiddler).
- Then look at what the response looks like after a valid successful login:

  - Find some reliable info on that "success" page that you can use to know that a login was successful. For example, you can search for specific strings / HTML snippets that serve as "success markers". You may also be able to use other characteristics of the HTTP response, like the response code, redirects that take place, etc. It all depends on how the remote server behaves after a successful login vs. a failed login.
- Keep in mind, the remote website could change their HTML format at any time, which could break your logic. Hence, choose a strategy that is least likely to break, if it's possible to make such an assumption.

  - One great thing to plan for this possibility, is write a "monitor" program that you run on a scheduled basis, that will test the logic you use to determine a successful login.
  - Encapsulate the code that does this action in a class library, so both your ASP.Net app, and your monitor program can share it.
  - Have the monitor program alert you (e.g. email) if it loses the ability to login or interpret a successful login on the remote site. This way you can immediately start working on fixing it, before your users notice.
  - Host the monitor app as a Windows Service, or if not possible, a console app that runs in Task Scheduler.
  - Be polite to the remote website, and only run the monitor 1-2 times a day if possible. That may be plenty of time for you to react to an issue, depending on your project requirements.

The class you're looking for in the .NET framework is `HttpWebRequest`. Here are some examples that can get you started with the code:

- [HttpWebRequest POST and Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581755/httpwebrequest-post-and-cookies)
- [login with VB.NET and httpwebrequest cookiecontainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820643/login-with-vb-net-and-httpwebrequest-cookiecontainer)

Comment: So if I understand correctly I have to pass a custom http header through a request that emulates the one that would be sent by the browser from the web page. Then, I parse the response sent from the remote server for something that indicates that it was successful. I would never have thought of doing it that way. I am not 100% sure on the TOS stuff but i'll cross that bridge when i get there. I have to give you credit for offering a broad enough solution that I can work with it to meet my needs. bravo.

Comment: Yes, I would expand on that and say you are setting multiple HTTP headers, as well as the HTTP request body-you want your programmatic web request to look exactly like a manual web request made through the browser. The HttpWebRequest class will let you do this by setting various properties, etc. to control the HTTP headers and body. Use Fiddler to compare your programmatic request with a manual request until differences are eliminated, and you will be well on your way. And if the remote website's architecture forces you to do two requests for reasons cited, then incorporate that too.